# Database connection not working in Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, curl

Hi I am following along an article and can't really get across a POST api.
I am using modulus for connecting to database uri.

Here's my code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:node@jello.modulusmongo.net:27017/hygeBe9b');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.port || 8080;

var router = express.Router();

//middleware to use for all requests

router.use(function(req, res, next){
console.log('Something is going on here !');

next();
})
router.get('/', function(req, res){
res.json({
    message: "Welcome to first API coding !"
})
});


router.route('/songs')
.post(function(req, res){
    var song = new Song();
    song.name  = req.body.title;

    song.save(function(err) {
        if (err) { res.send(err);}
        res.json({message : 'Song Created'});
    })
})
var Song = require('./models/songs');


app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server running on port: ' + port);
```

Model file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SongsSchema = new Schema({
 title: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Song', SongsSchema);
```

Here's my postman request code

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 5b280358-3de8-b52c-590b-430f5f4b6766" -d 'title=demo' "http://localhost:8080/api/songs"`

The https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

And importantly how can I debug my code to see where the error lies ?  API seems fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can check this one and see what error shown in your console:

```
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbName', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Could not connect to MongoDB!', err);
    }
});
```

connection syntax:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://[user]:[pass]@[hostAddress]:[port]/[databaseName]',callbackFunc)
```

for localhost

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/databaseName',callbackFunc)
```

**N.B:** Ensure first your `mongod` is running

Comment: I can do with localhost without username/password. But even when I try with a user/password it doesn't work. So basically uri with username and password doesn't work in case of localhost and remote db.

Comment: { [MongoError : auth failed] name: 'Mongo Error', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }

Comment: it seems authentication error means userName or password invalid for db. check it correctly

Comment: I think I will get to the modulus team as my username and password are correct. Accepting your answer as it helped me to console the error through callback in nodejs